# How to restrict a cdkDrag element to be drag only beside a particular element?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

Say I use `ngFor` to populate my `cdkDropList`. What is the most efficient way to restrict a `cdkDrag` element to only drag beside certain elements?

Comment: By beside if you mean wrapping inside a wrapper element and define bound than there is already official example for it https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples#cdk-drag-drop-boundary